# Adding firebase-ads dependency causes my app to crash

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I am a beginner in android development.
I am trying to add admob with firebase in my app but when I add firebase-ads dependency in gradle file, it causes the app to crash.
When I remove the dependency and run the project it works fine but when I add firebase-ads dependency`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.2'` then my app crashes.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: Martin Zeitler,  firebase is connected in my app but the problem is when I add dependency for admob then my app crashes

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Let me give you some advices: always add your code and the error log. With the current state of your question we can't help you in a granular way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an older version, it happened to me too, so I *downgrade it* to **16.0.1** and now it works fine :D

Answer (score -1):

As a beginner, use Firebase assistant from **Tools** > **Firebase** > **AdMob** to implement it automatically.